# Please set theme of AdActivity to @android:style/Theme.Translucent to enable transparent background interstitial ad

Tags: android, manifest, ads, interstitial, mopub

I get the above message in logs and as a result, I believe I do not get as many interstitial ads as I can. I have already updated my manifest with the following line

```
    <activity android:name="com.millennialmedia.android.MMActivity" 
         android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" 
         android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|keyboard" />
```

But I still get this error. Apparently there is something else I need to do to get this working.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Maybe you need to add AdActivity to your manifest file?

```
    <activity
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" />
```

and set theme to it?

Answer (score 5):

Add the android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" into manifest file. Same as follow

```
    <activity
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" />
```